# fatal: repository 'https://github.com/username/application.git/' not found

Tags: git, github

I added the remote url to my reactjs project and I followed these steps

```
git init
git remote add origin https://github.com/user_name/application_name.git
```

then I staged all the files and committed my changes to the branch

```
git add .
git commit -m 'initial commit'
```

while running below command ,it throwed repository not found error
`git push --set-upstream origin master`

then I checked remote url,username and email everything is correct

Don't know where it is going wrong.

Comment: Is the repository private?

Comment: Did you add `https://github.com/username/application.git` literally, or `username` and `application` are just placeholders that you replaced to ask the question?

Comment: those are placeholders

Comment: private resposity @dan1st

Comment: Maybe you are not logged in to GitHub/need to add your credentials to git (the CLI).

Comment: @dan1st I have checked username and email using git config commands in the terminal and username and email are proper

Comment: I am not talking about the config for committing. I am talking about the username/password (or PAT or other token) for pushing

Comment: I would also check the name of your branch on github.  By default, github creates the default branch as "main", but older git's defaulted to calling it "master".  I think you will want to rename your local branch to "main" to get the tracking right.

Comment: local branch name is in sync with git hub branch

Comment: @dan1st how we can check ?

Comment: You might want to check your [credential helper](https://git-scm.com/doc/credential-helpers). Also, it might be easier to test pushing on a public repository first. With GitHub, you probably want to login via OAuth.

Comment: @dan1st Create a public repository and added remote url to the existing project and while pushing permission denied to username(this username is different from what I saw in git config --list)

Comment: Then you are logged in with the wrong user. `git config` is completely unrelated to that user. Check your credential helper.